# Angularjs accessing controller value with string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i'm trying to create a table directive for my app, i would like to make it really flexible so, i can use it everywhere. The thing is that i don't know how to access the data from the string i'm trying to pass, maybe it's not the best way... any suggestions? Here is the code of both, html and directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module("private.directives")

    .directive('tableDirective', [
                                           function(){

        return {

            restrict : 'E',
            templateUrl: 'resources/js/private/views/utils/table/table.html',
            scope : {
                selected: '=',
                page : '=',
                header : '=',
                properties : '='
            },
            controller : ['$scope', function ($scope) {

            }],
            controllerAs : 'cntrl',
            bindToController: true
        }
}]);
```

The table html:

```
<div class="pt-1">      
            <table class="table table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr ng-repeat="header in headers">
                  <th translate>{{header | uppercase}}</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="data in cntrl.page.data" ng-class-odd="'striped'">
                  <td>{{data.[cntrl.properties[$index]] | uppercase}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

            <!-- TODO -->
            <div class="row" ng-show="cntrl.page.totalResults > 0">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <nav class="float-xs-right" aria-label="Page navigation">
                      <ul class="pagination">
                        <li class="page-item">
                          <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
                            <span class="sr-only" translate>paginacion.previous</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item active"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
                        <li class="page-item">
                          <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
                            <span class="sr-only" translate>paginacion.next</span>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And the HTML where is called:

```
   <table-directive 
        page="cntrl.ingredients" 
        headers="['#', 'table.name', 'tabla.brand']"
        properties="['ingredientId','description','brandDescription']">
    </table-directive>
```

The data in the "cntrl.ingredients" is an object with the followings:

```
{
   data : [],
   currentPage : null,
   pageSize : null,
   totalResults : null,
   sortDirection : null,
   orderBy : null
}
```

Where the "data" array will have diferent objects depending the table i'm using. I know the error is in the table html when i iterate over the cntrl.page.data, i don't know how to get the value i want to be show... "data.[cntrl.properties[$index]]" does not seem to be working.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your idea is valid, if you posted exactly the way you have coded, then it's just because there are some typos and minor mistakes.

`directive`:

1. you are expecting `header` and when calling directive, you have used `headers`
2. generally, if directive is the end consumer of data, then don't do `=` two-way binding but use `<` notion. this way your original data will not be modified. I am saying it because you have nothing in the directive's controller

`table.html`

1. repeat on `header in cntrl.headers` instead of `header in headers`. your headers info is bound to `cntrl` not directly to the scope.
2. I believe what you want is repeat on `th` not `tr`
3. for page data do:

   ```
    <tr ng-repeat="data in cntrl.page.data">
      <td ng-repeat="(key, value) in data" ng-class-odd="'striped'">{{value | uppercase}}</td>
    </tr>
   ```

cheers!

——- EDIT ——-

My bad. For page data, you were passing properties to ensure the order, right?
td ng-repeat should be on properties and call data[property]

--- EDIT2 ---

it should look like

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in cntrl.page.data">
  <td ng-repeat="property in cntrl.properties">
    {{ data[property] }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: imagine i have the following data array: [{'ingredientId' : 1, 'date' :'04/10/91', 'description' : 'ingredient1','brandDescription' : 'brand1'}, {'ingredientId' :2,'description' : 'ingredient2','brandDescription' : 'brand2'}].

The thing is i´m not sure how to link what i have to print with the properties i'm reciving, i thought it was "data.[cntrl.properties[$index]]" but is not working for me, i'm getting an Angular error

Comment: I have added the ng-repeat part. but what kinda error do you see? when I tested your code with the mentioned fixes, it did work

Comment: you were right, the problem was the dot in {{data.[cntrl.properties[$index]] instead of {{data[cntrl.properties[$index]]